# Hovering over cells display certain values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

So right now I have this calendar set-up:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCoOF.jpg - can't post images yet

And I have a formula like:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("Yes",'HI Project Database'!D2)), ('HI Project Database'!$B2&" - "&'HI Project Database'!$A2), "")
```

In the cells to pull data based on certain conditions from a separate spreadsheet.

Now I want to also display certain values if you hover the cells, specifically display text pulled from the "HI Project Database" sheet from cells AB:AG with commas and spaces in between.

What's the best way to go about doing this?